# Assigning datetime as index does not give DatetimeIndex

Tags: pandas, datetimeindex

My df has a field called "days". I need to create a datetime from "days" and a startdate. Probably cumbersome, but it works:

```
for t in df.index:
    df.loc[t,'date']=datetime.date(startdate)+
    datetime.timedelta(days=df.loc[t,'days'])
df.index=df.date
```

When I try to upsample:

```
udf=df.resample('M',how='sum')
```

I get:

> TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or
>   PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'

If I am setting the index with a datetime field, why doesn't the index become a datetime index (or "DatetimeIndex")? Each entry in "date" and the index are both datetime, are they not?

```
type(df.date[0])
<type 'datetime.date'>

type(df.index[0])
<type 'datetime.date'>
```

The way around it is:

```
df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

But I can't find any explanation as to why assigning an existing datetime to the index doesn't work, but converting an existing datetime (df.index) to a datetime via pd.to_datetime(df.index) does.

Comment: it's literally insane that this doesn't work as expected

Answer (score 2):

Pandas does not convert python native `datetime` objects to `Timestamp` objects from which `datetimeindexs` can be created. Reading the [pandas.DatetimeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) documentation will help.

The problem is that having `datetime` objects for your date column does not create a pandas `Timestamp` object. Pandas `Timestamp` is Pandas replacement for `datetime.datetime`

> Timestamp is the pandas equivalent of python’s Datetime and is interchangeable with it in most cases. It’s the type used for the entries that make up a DatetimeIndex, and other timeseries oriented data structures in pandas.

check out the [pandas.Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timestamp.html) documentation

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10,4), columns = list('abcd')) # sample df
df.index = pd.date_range(start='2018-1-1', end='2018-1-10') # use pandas to create a date range and set index
df['date'] = pd.date_range(start='2018-1-1', end='2018-1-10') # also set as column values
print(f"date column type: {type(df['date'][0])}\ndate index type: {type(df.index)}\n")

df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.date(x)) # convert pandas timestamp to datetime.date
print(f"type for datetime.date: {type(df['date'][0])}")

df.set_index('date', inplace=True) # set datetime.date as index
print(f"type for datetime.date as index: {type(df.index)}")
```

out:

```
date column type: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
date index type: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex'>

type for datetime.date: <class 'datetime.date'>
type for datetime.date as index: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'>
```

see the first and third outputs:

`<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>` vs `<class 'datetime.date'>`