# pandas Sqlite and resample error Only valid with DatetimeIndex

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am experimenting with pandas and sqlite to read data into a dataframe.

I think this code to resample to hourly averages worked if I were reading from a CSV file, but I am not sure why from Sqlite? Sorry I know very little about db any tips greatly appreciated..

If I run the code below I can print the first df but the resample errors:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import sqlite3


con = sqlite3.connect('./save_data.db')
df = pd.read_sql("SELECT * from all_data", con, index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)
df.set_index('Date')
print(df)

hourly_avg['kW'] = df['kW'].resample('H').mean()

print('hourly_avg.kW', hourly_avg.kW)
```

Output:

```
>>> 
=== RESTART: C:\Users\Desktop\tester\Test.py ===
                            Date         kW
0     2020-10-08 12:23:30.968967  68.129997
1     2020-10-08 12:25:39.375298  68.129997
2     2020-10-08 12:26:52.939991  68.129997
3     2020-10-08 12:27:57.839540  68.129997
4     2020-10-08 12:29:02.382524  68.129997
...                          ...        ...
1917  2020-10-09 10:14:35.113254  68.149994
1918  2020-10-09 10:15:08.840759  68.189995
1919  2020-10-09 10:15:41.873328  68.249992
1920  2020-10-09 10:16:14.953312  68.289993
1921  2020-10-09 10:16:48.043465  68.289993

[1922 rows x 2 columns]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\tester\Test.py", line 11, in <module>
    hourly_avg['kW'] = df['kW'].resample('H').mean()
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8087, in resample
    offset=offset,
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 1269, in get_resampler
    return tg._get_resampler(obj, kind=kind)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\resample.py", line 1435, in _get_resampler
    "Only valid with DatetimeIndex, "
TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'
>>>
```

***EDIT***

This appeared to work converting the datetime index from `index` to `DatetimeIndex`

`df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)`

[See this other SO POST.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677957/assigning-datetime-as-index-does-not-give-datetimeindex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `Datetimeindex` and your forgot the `inplace=True`

try this:

```
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

instead of this:

```
df.set_index('Date')
```

this should solve it.

You can get more information about **Datatimeindex** [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html)

Comment: Thanks... Would you know why my `df.index` doesnt change to a `Datetimeindex`? No matter what I try the df.index is only staying type `Index`

Comment: I wonder if there is something funny with my data that Pandas wont convert to the Datetimeindex???

Comment: Actually I figured this out... `df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)` on this other SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677957/assigning-datetime-as-index-does-not-give-datetimeindex

Comment: Nice :D ! Just remember that in some cases you have to put "inplace=True".  Take a look in your output of 'print(df)'.